# La forme de l'article indéfini (Via Mala, John Knittel, Albin Michel p. 417)

Tags: articles

> *Via Mala*, John Knitte
>
> — Tu viens pour longtemps sœur?
> Elle regardait distraitement quelques hommes et quelques femmes en noir qui montaient la route du village. Le bulbe doré du clocher du village luisait au soleil.
> — Je ne sais pas, Niclaus, dit-elle. Attendons qu'on soit entré dans l'église. Je n'ai pas envie de rencontrer des gens en chemin.

La question porte sur la règle de la transformation de l'article indéfini avant un cod d'une forme verbale négative.

> (Kalmbach, Forme *de* devant CVD )
>
> Quand l’ar­ti­cle in­dé­fi­ni (tou­tes les for­mes, c’est-à-dire singulier, pluriel et massif) dé­ter­mi­ne un grou­pe no­mi­nal qui est com­plé­ment de ver­be direct (CVD) d’un ver­be à la for­me né­ga­ti­ve, il prend gé­né­ra­le­ment la for­me ***de*** :
>
> • J’ai une voiture. vs Je n’ai pas en­co­re de voiture.
> • J’ai remar­qué des fautes. vs Je n’ai pas remar­qué de fautes.
> • Nous n’avons pas appris de mots nouveaux.
> • Aujourd’hui, je n’ai pas eu besoin de prendre de médicaments.
> • Ne fais pas de bruit.
>
> **Exceptions**
>
> Cepen­dant, cette règle de la transformation de l’ar­ti­cle dans une phra­se né­ga­ti­ve ne s’applique pas sys­té­ma­ti­que­ment. L’ar­ti­cle in­dé­fi­ni peut conserver sa for­me nor­ma­le dans les cas sui­vants.
>
> **Néga­tion par­tielle**
>
> L’ar­ti­cle in­dé­fi­ni devant CVD d’une phra­se né­ga­ti­ve devient de quand la néga­tion est totale. Ex­em­ple : le lo­cu­teur devait acheter des pommes et ne l’a pas fait, il dit :
>
> • Je n’ai pas acheté de pommes.
>
> Donc il est revenu sans les pommes prévues, le com­plé­ment du ver­be est « nié » com­plè­tement (com­plé­ment = « zéro, rien »). De mê­me, dans la phra­se sui­vante, on dit que la police n’a rien trouvé qui puisse servir à accuser le suspect (com­plé­ment = « zéro, rien ») :
>
> • La police n’a pas pu trouver de preuves contre le suspect.
>
> Mais la néga­tion peut aus­si être partielle : le ver­be peut avoir un com­plé­ment, mais ce com­plé­ment est dif­fé­rent de celui prévu ou supposé. Dans ce cas, l’ar­ti­cle reste généralement à la for­me nor­ma­le *des/du/de la/de*. Dans la phra­se sui­vante, la per­son­ne a bien acheté quel­que chose, mais ce ne sont pas des pommes. Ce qui est nié est la nature du com­plé­ment, et non pas le com­plé­ment tout entier :
>
> • Je n’ai pas acheté des pommes, j’ai acheté des cerises.

Le personnage à qui est imputée la phrase est sensé avoir une bonne instruction. Il n'est pas non plus question d'une opposition, par exemple, comme après une question telle que « Tu as peur qu'on rencontre des bandits ? ». Apparemment, il n'existe pas pour cette règle de principe de la langue parlé, comme dans le cas du changement de forme avant un adjectif, qui veut qu'en parlant il soit acceptable de dire, par exemple, « Il y avait des petits bouleaux le long du ruisseau. » au lieu de « … de petits… ».

La question est  de savoir si la règle ci-dessus remonte à une date ultérieure à la période où le livre a été écrit, ou s'il existe aussi un usage de langue parlée qui n'est pas mentionné dans les grammaires, ou s'il s'agit tout simplement d'une erreur du traducteur ?

Comment: La négative dans "Je n'ai pas envie de rencontrer des gens" ne concerne pas directement les gens mais l'envie, ce qui explique certainement une plus grande souplesse d'usage.

Comment: @guillaume31 Tout à fait à mon avis. Faisons ça avec des pommes. On dit "je n'ai pas envie de pommes aujourd'hui", mais pas "je n'ai pas envie des pommes" (si pommes n'est pas défini bien sûr). Par contre on dit indifféremment, "je n'ai pas envie de manger de pommes" ou "je n'ai pas envie de manger des pommes". "je n'ai pas envie de manger de pommes"  : "de pommes" dépend de "ne pas avoir envie";   "Je n'ai pas envie de manger des pommes" : "des pommes" dépend de "manger".

Answer (score 1):

Dans

> "Je n'ai pas envie de rencontrer des gens en chemin",

je ne vois pas d'erreur. Mais

> "Je n'ai pas envie de rencontrer de gens en chemin"

semble également correct.

J'ai du mal à distinguer une différence. Je dirais que la première version est un peu plus naturelle à mon oreille que la seconde.

Comment: C'est votre habitude du français qui vous inspire cette réponse ; c'est une bonne chose, ça pourrait déjà commencer à confirmer qu'il existerait un relâchement accepté dans la langue parlée. Je vois une différence de sens qui ressort dans la règle précisément expliquée dans la référence (Kalmbach). Pour cette raison il faudrait une référence pour supporter ce qui est avancé.

Comment: @LPH Il y a peut-être une nuance, mais elle est ténue ou bien en train de disparaitre, à mon avis. Je dirais que dans cet exemple, "des" est peut-être moins soutenu, ou moins "vieux" que "de"? Mais je ne suis pas tout à fait sûr. Pas facile. J'ai fait un sondage très rapide autour de moi, et les avis sont partagés, mais les deux formes paraissent acceptables.

Comment: La règle enseignée est que, dans une phrase négative, "des" se trandforme en "de", dès lors que le nom n'est pas précédé par un adjectif. Tentative d'explication : Si l'on ne référence aucune pomme, on choisit une forme indéfinie. S'il il n'y a plus de pommes rouges, l'article défini peut être une option : "*je n'ai pas acheté des pommes rouges comme tu me l'avais demandé, mais j'ai trouvé des Golden*.